# Fail2ban with Hipchat server

Tags: fail2ban

Has anyone managed to get fail2ban working with hipchat server?

I've found the log file and here's an example of a failure;

```
Authentication for 'user@domain.com' failed. HTTP code: 403, XMPP error: not-authorized, message: null
```

Any pointers on writing the filter.d file ?

Answer (score 1):

If that is the full log messages then fail2ban will not work with it. Fail2ban requires that a log message contains a datetime which it can parse. The regex you supply is then matched against what is left once the datetime has been parsed and removed. Your log message appears to be missing the relevant datetime.